# Populate MPAndroidChart BarChart from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, mpandroidchart

I have learned how to create a MPAndroidChart Bar chart from fixed data, but need to create one from a database. I looked on here and in the documentation without any help. Instead of the barEntries array list, I want to query the transactions table for the sum of the income by income category. Here is the query:

```
SELECT SUM(income),income_category FROM transactions GROUP BY income_category;
```

Below is the code with fixed data:

```
public class CYIncomeChartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SQLiteDatabase mSQLiteDatabase;

    BudgetDbHelper mDBHelper;

    SQLiteDatabase mSQLiteDatabase;

    // Database helper object //
    private BudgetDbHelper mDbHelper;

    BarChart barChart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cy_income_chart);

        barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.cy_income_chart);

        barChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
        barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
        barChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(50);
        barChart.setPinchZoom(false);
        barChart.setDrawGridBackground(true);

        ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();

        barEntries.add(new BarEntry(1, 40f));
        barEntries.add(new BarEntry(2, 44f));
        barEntries.add(new BarEntry(3, 30f));
        barEntries.add(new BarEntry(4, 36f));

        BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "Data Set1");
        barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        BarData data = new BarData(barDataSet);
        data.setBarWidth(0.9f);

        barChart.setData(data);

        String[] months = new String[] {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May","Jun"};
        XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter(months));
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);

    }

    public class MyXAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {

        private String[] mValues;
        public MyXAxisValueFormatter(String[] values) {

            this.mValues = values;
        }

        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {

            return mValues[(int)value];
        }
    }
}
```

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following :-

1) Create a method in the **BudgetDbHelper** class to return an **Arraylist** along the lines of:-

```
public ArrayList<BarEntry> getBarEntries() {
    String income_sum_column = "income_sum";
    SQliteDatabase db = this.getWriteableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[]{"SUM(income) AS " + income_sum_column,"income_category"};
    Cursor csr = db.query("transactions",columns,null,null,"income_category",null,null);
    ArrayList<BarEntry> rv = new ArrayList<>();
    while(csr.moveToNext()) {
        rv.add(new BarEntry(
            csr.getInt(csr.getColumnindex("income_category")),
            csr.getFloat(csr.getColumnIndex(income_sum_column))
        )
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

2) In the `CYIncomeChartActivity` instantiate `mDbHelper` e.g. :-

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cy_income_chart); //<<<< as is
    mDbHelper = new BudgetDbHelper(this); //<<<< assumes signature is just context
```

3) Retrieve, at the/an appropriate place, the ArrayList from the db by calling the method `getBarEntries` e.g.

```
   ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = mDbHelper.getBarEntries();
```

4) Use the returned ArrayList instead of the hard coded one.

- **Note** the above code is in-principle code and has not been tested so it may contain errors.

Comment: Thanks Mike, you got me a lot closer than I was before. I made a few tweeks to your code and debugged showing it pulling the data from the database but somehow when I go to setData, it is a null value and crashes? Below is the code.

Comment: Here is the class added to BudgetDbHelper: public ArrayList<BarEntry> getBarEntries() {
        String income_sum_column = "income_sum";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = new String[]{"SUM(income) AS " + income_sum_column,"income_category"};
        Cursor csr = db.query("transactions",columns,null,null,"income_category",null,null);
        ArrayList<BarEntry> rv = new ArrayList<>();
        while(csr.moveToNext()) {

Comment: rv.add(new BarEntry(
                    csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex("income_category")),
                    csr.getFloat(csr.getColumnIndex(income_sum_column))
            ));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    } And below is the CYIncomeChartActivity:

Comment: public class CYIncomeChartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    // Database helper object //
    private BudgetDbHelper mDbHelper;

    BarChart barChart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cy_income_chart);

        mDbHelper = new BudgetDbHelper(this);
        sqLiteDatabase = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = mDbHelper.getBarEntries();

Comment: BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries,"Income By Income Category");
        barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
        barData.setBarWidth(0.9f);

        barChart.setData(barData);

    }


} Any idea why it is giving me a null value after I debug and show the query to be pulling the data from the database?